# dask.distributed: handle serialization of exotic objects?

Tags: python, serialization, dask, dask-distributed

### Context

I am trying to write a data pipeline using dask distributed and some legacy code from a previous project. `get_data` simply get *url:str* and *session:ClientSession* as arguments and return a pandas DataFrame.

```py
from dask.distributed import Client
from aiohttp import ClientSession
client = Client()
session: ClientSession = connector.session_factory()

futures = client.map(
    get_data, # function to get data (takes url and http session)
    urls,
    [session for _ in range(len(urls))],  # PROBLEM IS HERE
    retries=5,
)
r = client.map(loader.job, futures)
_ = client.gather(r)
```

### Problem

I get the following error

```
 File "/home/zar3bski/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/poc-dask-iG-N0GH5-py3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/distributed/worker.py", line 2952, in warn_dumps
    b = dumps(obj)
  File "/home/zar3bski/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/poc-dask-iG-N0GH5-py3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/distributed/protocol/pickle.py", line 58, in dumps
    result = cloudpickle.dumps(x, **dump_kwargs)
  File "/home/zar3bski/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/poc-dask-iG-N0GH5-py3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/cloudpickle/cloudpickle_fast.py", line 73, in dumps
    cp.dump(obj)
  File "/home/zar3bski/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/poc-dask-iG-N0GH5-py3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/cloudpickle/cloudpickle_fast.py", line 632, in dump
    return Pickler.dump(self, obj)
TypeError: cannot pickle 'TaskStepMethWrapper' object
Unclosed client session
client_session: <aiohttp.client.ClientSession object at 0x7f3042b2fa00>
```

My temptation was then to register a serializer and a deserializer for this exotic object following [this doc](https://distributed.dask.org/en/stable/serialization.html#id3)

```py
from distributed.protocol import dask_serialize, dask_deserialize
@dask_serialize.register(TaskStepMethWrapper)
def serialize(ctx: TaskStepMethWrapper) -> Tuple[Dict, List[bytes]]:
    header = {} #?
    frames = [] #?
    return header, frames


@dask_deserialize.register(TaskStepMethWrapper)
def deserialize(header: Dict, frames: List[bytes]) -> TaskStepMethWrapper:
    return TaskStepMethWrapper(frames) #?
```

The problem is that I don't know where to load `TaskStepMethWrapper` from. I know that class `TaskStepMethWrapper` is asyncio related

```
grep -rnw './' -e '.*TaskStepMethWrapper.*'
grep: ./lib-dynload/_asyncio.cpython-310-x86_64-linux-gnu.so : fichiers binaires correspondent
```

But I couldn't find its definition anywhere in **site-packages/aiohttp**. I also tried to use a `Client(asynchronous=True)` with only resulted in a `TypeError: cannot pickle '_contextvars.Context' object`.

How do you handle exotic objects serializations in dask. Should I extend the dask serializer or use an additional [serialization family](https://distributed.dask.org/en/stable/serialization.html#serialization-families)?

```py
client = Client('tcp://scheduler-address:8786',
                serializers=['dask', 'pickle'], # BUT WHICH ONE
                deserializers=['dask', 'msgpack']) # BUT WHICH ONE
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a far easier to get around this: create your sessions within the mapped function. You would have been recreating the sessions in each worker anyway, they cannot survive a transfer

```
from dask.distributed import Client
from aiohttp import ClientSession
client = Client()

def func(u):
    session: ClientSession = connector.session_factory()
    return get_data(u, session)

futures = client.map(
    func,
    urls,
    retries=5,
)
```

(I don't know what loader.job is, so I have omitted that).

Note that `TaskStepMethWrapper` (and anything to do with aiohttp) sounds like it should be called only in async code. Maybe `func` needs to be async and you need appropriate `await`s.

Comment: Thanks @mdurant . I wanted to avoid this approach because `connector.session_factory()` ends up in regenerating an **oauth2 token** (invalidating previous tokens). That being said, I could forward the `Authorization` header and use it in the workers but it would involve some refactorization (and I have quite a lot of DBMS connectors). Good point about `async`. I tried it bu got a `TypeError: cannot pickle '_contextvars.Context' object`. I seems only to move the problem elsewhere

Comment: Then probably you also need to care about the return type of your function - if you specify the get_data function, maybe we can help. You can cache the session object if you need, by attaching to the Worker instance or in any imported module (*not* the "main" module you are invoking from).

Comment: Is an actor pattern relevant? I am also trying [this approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74615867/set-dask-workers-with-an-event-loop-for-actors)

Comment: No, I don't think you want actors. That's a way to route work to specific workers so that you can accumulate state. Caching the session is not *state* in that sense, you only do it once.