# set dask workers with an event loop for actors

Tags: python, asynchronous, dask, actor

### Context

I am trying to instantiate a **legacy** data extractor by my dask worker using an [actor pattern](https://distributed.dask.org/en/stable/actors.html)

```py
from dask.distributed import Client
client = Client()  
connector = Sharepoint(CONF.sources["sharepoint"])  
items = connector.enumerate_items()

# extraction
remote_extractor = client.submit(
    SharepointExtractor, CONF.sources["sharepoint"], connector, actor=True
)  # Create Extractor on a worker
extractor = remote_extractor.result()  # Get back a pointer to that object

futures = client.map(
    extractor.job,
    [i for i in items],
    retries=5,
    pure=False,
)
_ = await client.gather(futures)
```

The first thing the `SharepointExtractor` does is to get an http session from its connector

```py
class SharepointExtractor:
    def __init__(
        self, conf: ConfigTree, connector: Sharepoint, *args, **kwargs
    ) -> None:
        self.conf = conf
        self.session = connector.session_factory()
```

`.session_factory()` basically returns a [aiohttp.client.ClientSession](https://docs.aiohttp.org/en/stable/_modules/aiohttp/client.html#ClientSession) enriched with an Oauth token (which motivates the choice for an actor).

### The problem

at one point `ClientSession`'s constructor calls `asyncio.get_event_loop()` which does not seem available in the worker

```
...
 File "/home/zar3bski/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/poc-dask-iG-N0GH5-py3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/eteel/connectors/rest.py", line 96, in session_factory
    connector=TCPConnector(limit=30),
  File "/home/zar3bski/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/poc-dask-iG-N0GH5-py3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/aiohttp/connector.py", line 767, in __init__
    super().__init__(
  File "/home/zar3bski/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/poc-dask-iG-N0GH5-py3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/aiohttp/connector.py", line 234, in __init__
    loop = get_running_loop(loop)
  File "/home/zar3bski/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/poc-dask-iG-N0GH5-py3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/aiohttp/helpers.py", line 287, in get_running_loop
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/asyncio/events.py", line 656, in get_event_loop
    raise RuntimeError('There is no current event loop in thread %r.'
RuntimeError: There is no current event loop in thread 'Dask-Default-Threads-484036-0'.
```

Since I am in a dev/local context, from what I understand, I end up with a [LocalCluster](https://distributed.dask.org/en/stable/_modules/distributed/deploy/local.html#LocalCluster)

### Going async

I naively thought that going async would *automagicaly* inject the notion of event_loop into the workers.

```
client = await Client(asynchronous=True)  
connector = Sharepoint(CONF.sources["sharepoint"])
items = connector.enumerate_items()

# extraction
remote_extractor = await client.submit(
    SharepointExtractor, CONF.sources["sharepoint"], connector, actor=True
)  # Create Extractor on a worker
extractor = await remote_extractor  # Get back a pointer to that object
```

But the same error occurs

### Setting an event loop explicitly

```py
loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
client = await Client(
    asynchronous=True, loop=loop
)
```

This time, the error is slightly more enigmatic

```
....
  File "/home/zar3bski/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/poc-dask-iG-N0GH5-py3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/distributed/client.py", line 923, in __init__
    self._loop_runner = LoopRunner(loop=loop, asynchronous=asynchronous)
  File "/home/zar3bski/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/poc-dask-iG-N0GH5-py3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/distributed/utils.py", line 451, in __init__
    if not loop.asyncio_loop.is_running():
AttributeError: '_UnixSelectorEventLoop' object has no attribute 'asyncio_loop'
```

(not sure what this constructor is waiting for `loop`)

Do you have examples of dask actors involving resources from **aiohttp** (or any other async lib)? How should I set dask workers got get an event loop avaiblable to my actors?

### Edit

Following @mdurant approach (a kind of singleton based importation of the extractor from a importable module)

```py
def get_extractor(CONF):
    if extractor[0] is None:
        connector = Sharepoint(CONF.sources["sharepoint"])
        extractor[0] = SharepointBis(CONF.sources["sharepoint"], connector)
    return extractor[0]


def workload(CONF, item):
    extractor = get_extractor(CONF)
    return extractor.job(item)

def main(): 
    client = Client()
    connector = Sharepoint(CONF.sources["sharepoint"])
    items = connector.enumerate_items()
    futures = client.map(
        workload,
        [CONF for _ in range(len(items))],
        [i for i in items],
        retries=5,
        pure=False,
    )
    _ = client.gather(futures)
```

I still get

```
2022-12-01 10:05:54,923 - distributed.worker - WARNING - Compute Failed
Key:       workload-ffcf0f1a-8aee-41d1-9ad2-f7eea91fa107-41
Function:  workload
args:      (<eteel.conf.ConfGenerator object at 0x7fae8040d4e0>, 'firex1.sharepoint.com,930e9ef8-6bdf-4484-9883-6aa9965c548f,aed0d0bd-a659-4dbf-bbaa-a56f4efa3b0c')
kwargs:    {}
Exception: 'RuntimeError("There is no current event loop in thread \'Dask-Default-Threads-166860-1\'.")'
```

same goes with a `Client(asynchronous=True)`;which drives me back to my question: how can I have an event loop in a Dask Thread? I have a strong intuition that this has something to do with `Client(asynchronous=True, loop={this parameter})`

Comment: Question: why do you want this to be an actor workflow?

Comment: To avoid serializing exotic object and avoid the generation of thousands of sessions (one per item)

Comment: You do not need an actor for that.

Comment: What would you do?

Comment: Question: are the `items` serialisable?

Comment: the items, yes. The sessions, no

Answer (score 1):

OK, I think there is some confusion going on in this question, so I will do my best to clarify the situation. There are *three* main points:

- some things cannot be serialised between processes easily or at all
- some objects are expensive to create per process, and it would be nice to only do it once
- the work must happen in an async context

Here is how I would do it. Put this in an importable module.

```
extractor = [None]

def get_extractor(CONF):
    if extractor[0] is None:
        connector = Sharepoint(CONF.sources["sharepoint"])
        extractor[0] = SharepointExtractor(CONF.sources["sharepoint"], connector)
    return extractor[0]


async def workload(CONF, item):
    extractor = get_extractor(CONF)
    return await extractor.job(item, retries=5)

if __name__ == "__main__":  # or run this elsewhere
    client = ... 
    items = ...
    futures = client.map(workload, items)
    output = client.gather(futures)
```

I do not know from the OP which parts of the workload are coroutines, I am guessing the `.job` method - but it should be obvious what I am doing. I note the original code would not have worked in a simple non-dask session, and it is always best to start off with something that works before trying to daskify it.

On async in dask:

- client.map/submit supports coroutine functions, and they will be executed on the same event loop as the main worker. That's all you need here. All the distributed components (worker, scheduler, client) are async, server-like implementations with event loops, but execution of worker code does not normally happen in the same thread as the one running that server.
- client(asynchronous=True) implies that the client is to be constructed and operated on only from within coroutines - and that the client's event loop is in the current thread. This is probably not what you want, unless you know what you are doing.

Comment: As I understand it, every time `workload` is called, `SharepointExtractor()` constructor is called; ending in calling `.session_factory()` **for every item**. Am I understanding it correctly?

Comment: No! The first instance is stored in the mutable list for each worker. When the function is next run on a worker, it doesn't need to make a new instance.

Comment: OK, looks like an interesting way of dealing with it. I'll give it a shoot. Thanks

Comment: Just tried it and edited my post

Comment: Edited to add in your third constraint